# Query id which has dashes in it `a09d8-as8das-jlfj2k`

Tags: sql

My query evaluates to this:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE game_id = a09d8-as8das-jlfj2k LIMIT 3
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
var err  = new Error(code + ': ' + packet.message);
             ^
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'a09d8' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write query with apostrophes:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE game_id = 'a09d8-as8das-jlfj2k' LIMIT 3
```